# Usage of "gerne" in replying to questions

Tags: grammar-identification

> Möchtest du ein Stück Kuchen? - Ja, **gerne**.

> Kannst du mir bitte helfen? - Natürlich, **gerne**.

What type of grammatical object does "gerne" play in the above sentence?

Comment: I fail to see any special case in the given examples, a view also supported by the answer of HalvarF. Since the classification as adverb is stated in [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gerne), what caused your doubts?

Comment: Can you please make an effort to use proper umlauts and correct capitalization? Fixed it for you this time.

Comment: I don't have the umlaut symbol on my keboard. @Ingmar Capitlization ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What type of grammatical object does "gerne" play in the above sentence?

As has already been said by @HalvarF your examples are not "sentences". It is a common trait in languages to leave out implied parts. This is called an "ellipsis", which is greek and means "ommission". For instance:

> Q: What time is it?
> A: Eight

The person answering implies that "it is" and "o'clock" is so obvious that it isn't worth mentioning it. As every other language figure, this is not always appropriate, sometimes even bad style, but it is done nonetheless.

In your example "gerne" could be translated by "gladly so" or something similar.

> Kannst du mir bitte helfen? - Natürlich, gerne.
> <sub>Can you help me? Yes, [and I'll be] glad [to do so].</sub>

Basically, the "gerne" expresses that not only can one comply with what was asked, etc., but also that he will gladly do so. You can also hear that as an answer to people ordering in a restaurant or bar:

> "Ein Schnitzel und ein Bier, bitte."
> "Gerne."

Basically, the waiter is telling the guest that not only has he understood the order and is willing to deliver it, but he will also enjoy doing so.

You be the judge if this is anything more than a hollow phrase without any meaning if the waiter says it in response to every guests order automatically. But then "Guten Tag" doesn't usually mean the one saying it wishes the one addressed by this explicitly to have a good day either, so there is that.

Answer (score 0):

"Ja, gerne" and "Natürlich, gerne" aren't sentences.

The adjectives *natürlich* and *gerne* just answer the respective question in the form of qualifying it. You can call this an adverbial use of the adjectives because they refer to the respective verb/predicate of the question.

> Möchtest du ein Stück Kuchen? - Ja, gerne [möchte ich ein Stück Kuchen].
> Kannst du mir bitte helfen? Natürlich [und] gerne [kann ich dir helfen].

Comment: "Gerne möchte ich ein Stück Kuchen" ist schlechter Stil. Im "möchte" steckt das "gerne" schon drin. "Gerne esse ich ein Stück Kuchen" wäre gut. Ähnlich im 2. Beispiel: "Gerne helfe ich Dir" ist ok, aber "Gerne kann ich Dir helfen." qualifiziert die Fähig- oder Möglichkeit des Helfenkönnens als etwas Bevorzugtes.

Comment: @userunknown Richtlg , aber hier ging es ja darum, auf was sich "gerne" oder "natürlich" als Antwort auf diese beiden Fragen grammatisch bezieht, nicht darum, was als ganzer Satz guter Stil ist.

Comment: Ich verstehe Deine Backsteinklammern so, dass sie einen Teil markieren, der stillschweigend unterschlagen wird, dass man also den Satz ohne die Klammerzeichen sagen kann. Aber wenn ich sage, dass ich ein Stück Kuchen möchte ist das "gerne" mit dem "möchte" bereits ausgedrückt. Gerne hat man, oder isst man ein Stück Kuchen. Gerne ein Stück Kuchen mögen hebt die Betrachtung auf eine 2. Ebene des Mögens. Offenbar mag man nicht den Kuchen selbst, sondern das Mögen des Kuchens.

Comment: @user unknown "Ich möchte gerne" mag pleonastisch sein, das gibt aber nicht den Ausschlag bei der Beantwortung der Frage, ob es richtiges Deutsch ist. Hierbei kommt es allein auf den Sprachgebrauch an.